# UIView Animation breaks TableView

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, scroll, bounce

I have a UITableView embedded in a UIView.    When a cell is selected, the TableView slides left using UIView Animation so that details underneath can be displayed.     When I slide the tableview back to its original frame, the table view can be scrolled over the top of the other elements in the  Warpper View.     Before the animation, you could only scroll the tableview cells up and down within the boundaries of the tableview.   Why is this happening?

```
- (void)slideTableView:(BOOL)reset
{

    //Current pos
    CGRect newTableViewFrame = self.tableView.frame;

    //Determine direction based on current pos
    int newX;

    if (reset || newTableViewFrame.origin.x < 0) {
        newX = newTableViewFrame.origin.x=0;
    }
    else {
        newX = newTableViewFrame.origin.x - 280;
    }

    newTableViewFrame.origin.x =newX;

    CGFloat animationDuration = 0.2;
    CGFloat animationDelay = 0.0;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration delay:animationDelay options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{

                     self.tableView.frame=newTableViewFrame;

                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){


                 }];
}
```

Comment: I had added a shadow to the view earlier and used:

self.clipsToBounds = NO;
self.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
Simply setting back fixes the above:

self.clipsToBounds = YES;
self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

Answer (score 0):

I had added a shadow to the view earlier and used:

```
self.clipsToBounds = NO; 
self.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
```

Simply setting back fixes the above:

```
self.clipsToBounds = YES;  
self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```